# Linking Social Icons in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on my portfolio website using Bootstrap 3 but I am not quite sure as to how I would go about linking my social icons based on the html being that their are other elements occupying the section in which I would place the URL.

```
<li class="tooltip-social facebook-link">
    <a href="#facebook-page" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Facebook">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"> </i>
    </a>
</li>
```

Any assistance or solutions would be greatly appreciated. I look forward to your feedback. Thanking you all in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/PlayStation" target="_new"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="20" height="20"></a>
```

the above way you can give the link to your page. When you login into your facebook/twitter. copy the url and paste it, in FB url will be different only for the pages you have created. When you login into FB you will url has **www.facebook.com** only. Now i have selected a page created by playstation the url look like **www.facebook.com/PlayStation**